# How is ignore-paths evaluated in git svn?

Tags: regex, git, git-svn, ignore

I have a simple repo structure like this:

```
trunk
    code
    othercode
    doc
    misc
branches
    b1
        code
        othercode
        doc
        misc
    b2
tags
    t1
    t2
```

I'm trying to use `git svn` to clone it, but want to omit `doc` and `misc` on trunk + all tags and branches.  However, the `ignore-paths` option isn't acting like I'd expect.

```
ignore-paths = (doc|misc)
```

Seems to work, but I'm worried that it would also exclude a path like `trunk/code/proj1/doc/`, which I want to keep.

```
ignore-paths = ^(doc|misc)
```

Does not work -- `doc` and `misc` are pulled in by the initial `git svn fetch` command.  How do I get a working regex that'll only match against directories at the root like this?  The man page does not say whether `ignore-paths` matches against the "relative" path that'll end up at the root of the git clone (`doc`, etc.) or the "full" path as seen in the SVN remote (`branches/b1/doc` etc.), or something else.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems to match the full path in the SVN repository.  This regex, which includes the `trunk`/`tags`/`branches` portion of the SVN path, did the trick:

```
ignore-paths = ^(trunk|tags/[^/]*|branches/[^/]*)/(doc|misc)/
```

In words: the path must start with one of:

- `trunk`
- `tags/`, perhaps followed by one path segment (not containing `/`)
- `branches/`, perhaps followed by one path segment (not containing `/`)

... then path segment named `doc` or `misc`.

Comment: Is there a equival method for svn repos without svn layout?

Comment: @besnep, if you mean "without *the standard* svn layout", then I think yes: since the regex is matched against the full path, you can use it regardless of how your repository is laid out.

Comment: @MattMcHenry, not exactly. I meant by "without svn layout" that there is absolut no layout. A versionsplit was made by svn-copy. No SVN layout is used. So no trunk, no branch... if i understand it right.

Comment: @besnep, I think this probably warrants its own separate question; it's going to be hard to hash out in comments.

Comment: I could make a new separate question but befor that i would have to finde a solution to my other problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25358628/how-to-git-svn-clone-full-history-despite-svn-copy

Comment: can you explain your regex please?