# How to git svn clone full history despite svn copy

Tags: git, svn, clone, svn-copy

In my company we are about to switch from svn to git. The SVN we use is very big, doesn't have a svn layout and on every version split we made a svn copy.

SVN Repository structur:

- svnserver.company.de

  - product xy

    - majorversionnumber 1
    - majorversionnumber 2
    - majorversionnumber 3

      - minorversionnumber 3.0.0
      - minorversionnumber 3.0.1
      - minorversionnumber ...
    - majorversionnumber 4
    - ....
  - product zw

What we want or what i was expecting git to do:

git svn clone does clone all files from one subfolder / copy with the full history of these files (like tortoise does by unchecking "Stop on copy/rename").

What git is doing:

git svn clone --prefix=origin/ --username=spe --authors-file=authors.txt https://svnserver.company.de/repos/product/majorversionnumber/Master/Source product

->  does clone all files from one subfolder / copy but only with the history until the copy has taken place.

The Question:

**Has git a equivalent to svns "Stop on copy/rename" or how to clone full history despite svn copy?**

What i have found so far:
[Git-svn - import full history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15163916/git-svn-import-full-history)
[Work-around for failing "git svn clone" (requiring full history)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161541/work-around-for-failing-git-svn-clone-requiring-full-history)
https://github.com/githubtraining/zzz_deprecated-feedback/issues/43

To be honest, i didn't understand the solution approaches of these links neighter if they had the same problem as we do.

Comment: Please add some examples: What does your repo structure look like? How you invoke `git svn clone` (the options make a difference...)? What result do you expect from git-svn?

Comment: I've added an example of our svn repo structure and the git command. What result i expect is already under "What we want or what i was...".

Comment: Help us understand how the structure came to be this way; i.e. the history.  Say you were now going to create "majorversionnumber 5" of "product xy" -- what SVN command would you use to do that?  Similarly for "majorversionnumber 3.0.2", what's the SVN command?

Comment: major 5: New Folder in SVN in product xy named (in this example) "majorversionnumber 5" and a "master" folder in the major folder. Then a copy of the source from major 4 master to major 5 master.
SVN can track the history correct.

minor 3.0.2: New Folder in SVN in major 3 named "minor... 3.0.2". Then a copy of the source from major 3 master to this new Folder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to migrate SVN repository with history to a new Git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79165/how-to-migrate-svn-repository-with-history-to-a-new-git-repository)

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so if I understand correctly your full layout is like this:

```
svnserver.company.de
  product xy
    majorversionnumber 1
      master
        <actual source starts here>
    majorversionnumber 2
    majorversionnumber 3
      master
        <actual source starts here>
      minorversionnumber 3.0.0
        master
          <actual source starts here>
      minorversionnumber 3.0.1
      minorversionnumber ...
    majorversionnumber 4
    ....
  product zw
```

This is just an untested educated guess, but I'd try something like this.  First, `git svn init svn://svnserver.company.de`.  Then edit `.git/config`'s `[svn-remote]` section to look something like this:

```
fetch = product xy/majorversionnumber 1/master:refs/remotes/origin/trunk
branches = product xy/{majorversionnumber 2,majorversionnumber 3}/master:refs/remotes/origin/branches/*
branches = product xy/majorversionnumber 3/{minorversionnumber 3.0.0,minorverionnumber 3.0.1}/master:refs/remotes/origin/branches/*
```

Then `git svn fetch`.  You can use similar commands + config to create a clone for `product zw`.

See the `CONFIGURATION` section of `git help svn` for more details.